How to display a list of objects contained in an object
I have an object:
export interface Album {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  remarks: string;
  artist: Artist;
  albumType: AlbumType;
  songs: Song[];
}

I can display an Album. This works without a problem.
Now I want to display the songs contained on the album. How can I do that?
I tried this:
<tr *ngFor="let dataItem of {{album?.song}}">
  <td style="display:none;">{{dataItem.id}}</td>
  <td>{{dataItem.title}}</td>
  <td>{{dataItem.duration}}</td>
  <td>{{dataItem.remarks}}</td>
</tr>

But that doesn't work. I'm getting this error:
NG5002: Parser Error: Unexpected token {, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 18 in [let dataItem of {{album?.songs}}] in C:/Users/BSEBV60/source/repos/MusicAndBooksApplication/musicandbooksapplication.client/src/app/music/music-details/music-details.component.html@37:10

Can anyone help?

Where did you get the idea you needed {{}} inside the structural directive? See e.g. https://angular.dev/guide/directives#using-ngfor, https://angular.dev/tutorials/first-app/08-ngFor

@jonrsharpe So I don't need the {{}}. But then what do I need? Without the braces it doesn't work either.

Then give a [mre] of that, but it would fix the parser error on { at least.

This should do the job:
<tr *ngFor="let dataItem of album?.songs ?? []">
  <td style="display:none;">{{dataItem.id}}</td>
  <td>{{dataItem.title}}</td>
  <td>{{dataItem.duration}}</td>
  <td>{{dataItem.remarks}}</td>
</tr>

Remove {{}} in the *ngFor.
Use songs inetead of song.
